# Dynamic parameter for NTILE

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, batch-processing

I have table which will have row count between *25k* to *250k*. Now I need to divide this whole table in chunks for processing using `NTILE`. If I will give fixed count as `NTILE(4)`, It works fine for me. Do we have any way to pass parameter dynamically?

I want to maintain individual batch size to *25k*. So if table has *40k* rows parameter value should be *2*, If its *150k*, it should be *6* and so on...

Kindly suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: I suspect NTILE is not actually what you want. It's whole purpose for existing is to take any number of records and group them into a fixed set of equal-sized chunks. In your case, you want a variable set of chunks each of size 25k rows; so just use an expression over ROW_NUMBER(), e.g. `CEIL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id)/25000)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description it is not clear why you want to pass the parameter dynamically, and not have it as a static expression, perhaps something like

EDITED: initially I had the count in a subquery directly in the argument to `NTILE()`, but that doesn't work - not supported by the Oracle implementation.

This should work - tested on the EMP table in the SCOTT schema:

```
select empno, ename,
       ntile ( ceil(ct/4) ) over (partition by ct order by empno) as n_tile
from emp cross join ( select count(*) as ct from emp );

     EMPNO ENAME          N_TILE
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH               1
      7499 ALLEN               1
      7521 WARD                1
      7566 JONES               1
      7654 MARTIN              2
      7698 BLAKE               2
      7782 CLARK               2
      7788 SCOTT               2
      7839 KING                3
      7844 TURNER              3
      7876 ADAMS               3
      7900 JAMES               4
      7902 FORD                4
      7934 MILLER              4

 14 rows selected
```

So, the count of rows in the base table needs to be done separately, and then use a cross join (which is fine, because one of the tables has just one row).

So:

```
  select .....  ,  ntile ( ceil(ct/25000) ) over (partition by ct order by ..... ) 
  ....
  from <base_table> CROSS JOIN (select count(*) as ct from <base_table>)
```

Comment: Table will not have constant number of rows , at one point of time it can have 25k rows , at other 120k or so on.. If i will fix it to 4 then it will not work, I have to keep changing number based on row count. Writing query to get count does not work and gives error as it expects a constant.

Comment: I don't think you use "dynamic" correctly. Just passing in something that is not constant doesn't make it "dynamic". My solution includes an expression, it divides the count by 25,000 and rounds up - that is not "dynamic". I don't understand what you mean by "as it expects a constant" - can you show how you are using this?

Comment: Actually, I see the problem - you can't have a scalar subquery as part of the expression argument to `NTILE()`. Thinking of a workaround...

Comment: @Bhushan - sorry, the solution I posted originally was correct in concept, but didn't follow the Oracle rules. It's fixed now; same concept, just the way you write it must be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare 2 variables x for the NTILE(x) and y for the number of rows in your table.
First you assign y as count(*) of your table, then, using an if function you assign x according to y.

Comment: I am not sure how to declare variable in sql. I am not using PL/SQL here. Is it possible using SQL only? If yes , kindly share sample sql for same.

Comment: I guess from the tag that you are using oracle.

Comment: declare
 y number;
begin
  select count(*) into y from table;
end;